# JOIN on column only if NOT NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null

I'm in the process of re-writing an old SQL query and have troubles making sense out of it. It contains several conditions of the form

```
SELECT ...
FROM a, b, c
WHERE
c.id = ...
AND (
  a.x_id IS NULL
  OR a.x_id = c.x_id
)
AND b.id = a.b_id (+)
```

Can this query be rewritten using proper JOIN syntax? Is it equivalent to the following or will it produce different results under certain circumstances?

```
SELECT ...
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a
ON b.id = a.b_id
LEFT JOIN c
ON a.x_id = c.x_id
WHERE c.id = ...
```

The original query is 100 lines long and spans 5 tables, plus several joins over "virtual tables" (i.e. where conditions of the form `x.z_id = y.z_id`), which makes it hard to break down into more manageable bits or debug.

Comment: I advise you to set up a dev environment with the same data structure but containing less data, so you can split your request into small fragments like the one you posted, and debug it. You should give it a try, because in this case maybe someone will be able to give you an answer, but later, debug will be a real pain.

Answer (score 4):

if you want same result as you have in first query - you must make left join only with table a, like this :

```
SELECT ...
FROM  b, c
LEFT JOIN a
ON b.id = a.b_id and b.id = a.b_id
WHERE
c.id = ... b.c_id
```

or if you want the same style with all tables, you can use inner join with table b,  like this :

```
SELECT ...
FROM  c
INNER JOIN b
on b.c_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN a
ON b.id = a.b_id 
WHERE
c.id = ...
```

in my both query we select data from table b where column is not null

Comment: Duplication of `ON` and `WHERE` clause by accident or on purpose?

Comment: in this situation 'On' works with left join, and 'where' clause works with inner joins, in this situation b and c tables are inner joined

Comment: Why `ON b.id = a.b_id AND b.id = a.b_id`? That's the same condition twice.

Comment: It was a mechanical mistake